# SQL into ActiveRecord scope: Retrieve Records with given association, or whose nested objects have the given association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How do I translate this SQL into an ActiveRecord scope?

```
SELECT * FROM trxes 
WHERE date="2022-05-01" 
AND id IN (SELECT lines.trx_id FROM lines WHERE lines.category_id = 15) 
OR id IN (SELECT id FROM trxes WHERE trxes.category_id = 15)
```

The scope I'm using gets close but returns Trxes outside of May 2022.

```
scope :category_id, -> (cat_id) { where(lines: Line.where(category_id: cat_id)).or(Trx.where(category_id: cat_id)) }
```

> Trx.date("2022-May-01").category_id(15)
>
> Trx Load (0.3ms) SELECT "trxes".* FROM "trxes" WHERE ("trxes"."date" = ? AND "trxes"."id" IN (SELECT "lines"."trx_id" FROM "lines" WHERE "lines"."category_id" = ?)                        OR "trxes"."category_id" = ?) [["date", "2022-05-01"], ["category_id", 15], ["category_id", 15]]

**More information:** A *simple* Trx has a category= Fuel, Groceries, Entertainment..., and 0 Line objects. A *complex* Trx has category=Split, and it has multiple Line objects which themselves have a category= Fuel, Groceries, Entertainment...

I want to query Trx model for category=Fuel, and retrieve all simple Trxes where category=Fuel, and complex Trxes containing a Line that has category=Fuel.

```
class Trx < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category, optional: true
  has_many :lines, dependent: :destroy
...
class Line < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :trx
  belongs_to :category, optional: true
...
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :lines
  has_many :trxes
...
```

**Additional effort** I would like to combine the results of the following two ActiveRecord queries

```
Trx.where(date:"2022-May-01").where(category_id: 15)
Trx.where(date:"2022-May-01").where(lines: Line.where(category_id: 15))
```

Comment: Just combine your 2 queries with `or` as you did above?

Comment: @engineersmnky Ideally, I'll only call .where(date: ...) once. like: Trx.date("May").vendor("Target").category("Groceries").

I think my original scope isn't working bc within the OR clause, I'm querying against the entire set of Trx, instead of whatever is coming to me down the chain. "... .or(**Trx**.where(category_id: cat_id)) } ..."
Say I'm calling scope "category_id" after first Trx.where(date: "2022-05-01"). The first part of the scope searches Trxes with date "2022-05-01", but the second part searches Trx.all
If that makes sense (and is correct), how do I avoid searching Trx.all?

Comment: Oh, wow, my original scope works if I just remove the 'Trx' so `"...cat_id)).or(Trx.where(category_id..."` becomes `"...cat_id)).or(where(category_id..."`    
The new SQL is `SELECT "trxes".* FROM "trxes" WHERE "trxes"."date" = ? AND ("trxes"."category_id" = ? OR "trxes"."id" IN (SELECT "lines"."trx_id" FROM "lines" WHERE "lines"."category_id" = ?))`